# Avoiding 'but' in apologies and arguments

Tags: synonyms

I just recently came across a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/2rkp8j/lpt_when_apologizing_replace_the_word_but_with_a/) that started when a user gave following advice

> When apologizing, replace the word 'but' with a pause.

One of the comments even said (exaggerated) that everything before the 'but' is just for 'shutting up' the other person, and everything after it is what you actually want to say.

This made me think that when ever I hear a 'but' in one of those situations, I perceive it slightly the way that was just described, but on the other hand I use those 'but' phrases myself without wanting the person I am speaking to, to perceive it that way.

So what other wording is possible for situations like this, where you would like to avoid the 'but'?

Comment: I am not sure how this is a question about English. And I am not sure what you expect us to add that the 1000+ posts in that thread haven't.

Comment: I think most of the posts on reddit are of doubtable seriousness, and this phrasing of e.g. apologies is special to english since at least it does not exist that way in my native language, so I'd like to hear some more serious answers from people who are used to this language and perhaps already thought about this.

Comment: Their first example 'I'm sorry . . . I'm trying my best' still sounds mitigatory, a claiming of self-defence. Perhaps stopping after 'I'm sorry' is the answer sometimes. Or leaving a very long pause. 'I'm sorry' is used as:  a pure apology, a sign of empathy, and (when used as an introductory comment) pragmatically as a hedge on various levels (grading to an annoyance marker).

Comment: Do you want to make a 'non-apology apology', or do you want to express genuine contrition?

Comment: @AE I am looking for ways of expressing a gneuine contrition.

Comment: @flawr, then leave out the 'but *justification*' part entirely.

Comment: I think it is still important to have a chance at explaining what reason you did it (the action that 'hurt' the other person) for in order for the other person to understand that it was not your intention to harm the other person, and that therefore the appology is really heartfelt.

Comment: 'However' only costs a nickel more, and the person you're pretending to apologize to may be too stupid to notice it's a take-back when you start it with such a fancy qualifier.

Comment: Anything you add to the apology is likely to be interpreted as an excuse, not an explanation. It's a psychology issue, not an language issue; they'll see through however you try to phrase it. You can't win.

Answer (score 1):

> So what other wording is possible for situations like this, where you would like to avoid the 'but'?

You can often rephrase something that uses *but* with *however*, *though* or *that said*:

So with the canonical non-apology apology form:

> I'm sorry if you're offended but I'm right about everything and only saying this as a political move to stop your complains.

We can have.

> I'm sorry if your offended; however, I'm right about everything and only saying this as a political move to stop your complains.
>
> I'm sorry if you're offended, though I'm right about everything and only saying this as a political move to stop your complains.
>
> I'm sorry if you're offended. That said, I'm right about everything and only saying this as a political move to stop your complains.

There's also a colloquial form of *only* that would not generally be considered standard English, but would be widely understood:

> I'm sorry if you're offended, only I'm right about everything and only saying this as a political move to stop your complains.

This of course completely misses the point of the reddit post, which was not about the word *but* qua word, but about the fact that when it appears in an apology it's very often in exactly the form above where something seems to be an apology at first, but quickly retracts all of the actual apologising.

Looking for *but* in what you go to say isn't about the English language, its about realising you're about to say such a thing.

It's not *but* that's the problem. If *but* genuinely has a place in a genuine apology, then that is not what they were talking about.

Comment: Not to complicate things further, *but* [I'm going to] it's worth noting that *if*, as used in your example, is equally... nullifying? To say, "I'm sorry *if*..." implies that the speaker really doesn't understand why on Earth the victim would be hurt/offended. The implication is kinda like, "I'm sorry if you're offended. You shouldn't be. A reasonable person wouldn't be, and it doesn't at all make sense. But I guess I'm sorry anyway."

Comment: @EFrog totally why I included it in my example. And again, *if* coming to your lips or typing fingers could be a sign that you are about to say or write such a thing, but it can just as reasonably be used in a genuine apology.

Answer (score 1):

The way to avoid offence is to avoid using a connecting word (but, however, although etc) which appears to limit (and thereby to detract from) what would otherwise be an unqualified apology.

May I suggest "...**and**..." as useful in some circumstances?

Eg: "I'm very sorry indeed **and** I certainly didn't mean to act out of turn."